# Java's Random values differ each time

Tags: java, random

I want the Random to return the same values each time. So I tried giving it a const seed. But it still returns random values. How can I stop this?

EDIT: I use the same Random object all over my code, The first time I tested my program I got the following values from the random:

```
13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 80, 33, 3, 0, 45, 6, 2, 51, 50, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 33, 1, 22, 7, 55, 92, 33, 1, 5, 6, 10, 2, 1, 85, 26, 1, 3, 42, 16, 0, 2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 4, 97, 57, 85, 28, 0, 2, 3, 9, 36, 1, 19, 4, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 3, 0, 96, 84, 22, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0, 3, 0, 6, 1, 64, 39, 2, 0, 51, 31, 13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 80, 33, 3, 0, 45, 6, 2, 51, 50, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 33, 1, 22, 7, 55, 92, 33, 1, 5, 6, 10, 2, 1, 85, 26, 1, 3, 42, 16, 0, 2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 4, 97, 57, 85, 28, 0, 2, 3, 9, 36, 1, 19, 4, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 3, 0, 96, 84, 22, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0, 3, 0, 6, 1, 64, 39, 2, 0, 51, 31
```

The second time I got:

```
13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 33, 9, 61, 1, 2, 54, 59, 99, 28, 0, 88, 11, 0, 0, 92, 24, 0, 47, 43, 83, 13, 1, 1, 53, 46, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 13, 8, 1, 16, 6, 2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 0, 97, 57, 85, 28, 5, 2, 3, 3, 36, 4, 19, 0, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 1, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0, 13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 33, 9, 61, 1, 2, 54, 59, 99, 28, 0, 88, 11, 0, 0, 92, 24, 0, 47, 43, 83, 13, 1, 1, 53, 46, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 13, 8, 1, 16, 6, 2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 0, 97, 57, 85, 28, 5, 2, 3, 3, 36, 4, 19, 0, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 1, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0
```

The first couple of values are quite similar but the rest. Well, you can see

I use private static Random r = new Random(SEED); // The seed is never changed after this point
I also use this random to randomize byte arrays. The thing is, I'm getting different outputs for the same input. I wish I could post more code but it's a really big project to post here.

Comment: Can you add some more information about the context of your question. I am close to downvote this, because it seems like a joke to me, but I guess there must be a reason for this question, so I am really curious. The question seems paradox by nature to me. :-)

Comment: Now the problem is clear but the answer is "it shouldn't act like this". I think you need to post some code and/or more information on how you use the Random object.

Comment: I really don't understand some of the comments nor some of the answers: if you people don't understand why having a method returning pseudo-random numbers **yet always the same PRNs** can be **very** useful you have no business answering questions/commenting on SO.

Comment: You need to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two sequences are far from random sequences of integers. There is a lot of repetition and large parts of the sub-sequences equal each other. I believe you have some bug in your code.

Sequence 1:

```
13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0,

80, 33, 3, 0, 45, 6, 2, 51, 50, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 33, 1, 22, 7, 55, 92, 33, 1, 5, 6, 10, 2, 1, 85, 26, 1, 3, 42, 16, 0,

2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 4, 97, 57, 85, 28, 0, 2, 3, 9, 36, 1, 19, 4, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 3, 0, 96, 84, 22, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0, 3, 0, 6, 1, 64, 39, 2, 0, 51, 31,

13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0,

80, 33, 3, 0, 45, 6, 2, 51, 50, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 33, 1, 22, 7, 55, 92, 33, 1, 5, 6, 10, 2, 1, 85, 26, 1, 3, 42, 16, 0,

2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 4, 97, 57, 85, 28, 0, 2, 3, 9, 36, 1, 19, 4, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 3, 0, 96, 84, 22, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0, 3, 0, 6, 1, 64, 39, 2, 0, 51, 31
```

Sequence 2:

```
// In sync with sequence 1
13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0,

// Out of sync with sequence 1
2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 33, 9, 61, 1, 2, 54, 59, 99, 28, 0, 88, 11, 0, 0, 92, 24, 0, 47, 43, 83, 13, 1, 1, 53, 46, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 13, 8, 1, 16, 6,

// Back in sync!
2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 0, 97, 57, 85, 28, 5, 2, 3, 3, 36, 4, 19, 0, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 1, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0,

13, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 8, 6, 12, 9, 7, 7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0,

// Out of sync again...
2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 33, 9, 61, 1, 2, 54, 59, 99, 28, 0, 88, 11, 0, 0, 92, 24, 0, 47, 43, 83, 13, 1, 1, 53, 46, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 13, 8, 1, 16, 6,

// Back in sync....
2, 34, 0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 73, 1, 4, 66, 59, 49, 99, 2, 0, 97, 57, 85, 28, 5, 2, 3, 3, 36, 4, 19, 0, 0, 71, 9, 2, 3, 76, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 1, 58, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 21, 59, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 60, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 26, 4, 0, 25, 5, 0, 61, 2, 0, 29, 2, 1, 34, 57, 55, 61, 1, 1, 21, 6, 1, 3, 0, 56, 6, 23, 6, 0, 47, 1, 1, 55, 0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 0, 57, 21, 45, 2, 0
```

Comment: Well, I tried printing out all values generated from the random and yes, there seems to be something wrong. A boolean is printed where an integer is printed in another execution level. So I think it's the random behavior causing the problem. Thanks

Comment: @ComputerJy: The analysis of aioobe possibly indicates that you use the same Random object for generating other random numbers for other purposes. Consequently, the array does not contain the complete sequence, and it has "holes" in it. Check all the places where you use the same random generator.

Comment: its a private static object so it's not called from other classes, these are the nextInt calls, I also have nextBoolean and nextBytes calls, but I thought just the ints would be sufficient. Anyway, the reason in the code causing this is my latest question. Thanks again

Comment: private static object could still be called by other instances of the same class though...

Answer (score 6):

I can only see two ways in which this can happen:

1. The two executions don't share precisely the same order of invocation. There's something you're missing - e.g. some method invocation on the random object from some other thread or something. As PRNGs are completely deterministic, this is the most likely thing - I'm sure you already checked it but it still seems the most likely explanation.
2. You've found a bug in the PRNG. Unlikely but not impossible - if you provide us with details like Java version, seed used, etc. then maybe we could try and reproduce it.

In any case, I would strongly recommend you **create an "as short as possible" toy-application which can replicate the discrepancy, and then update your question with it if the problem persists**.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the most likely scenario (1.). As for 2. ... Looking at the source for juRandom there isn't much space for bugs. Heck, an LCG is almost impossible to get wrong algorithm-wise (the parameters are another matter, entirely).

Answer (score 4):

The following snippet of code should always produce the same output:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Random r = new Random(123456L);     // use the seed 123456L
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
7
7
5
```

To go back to "real" random behavior, simply remove the argument to the constructor (and it will pick a "random" seed).

---

For more information, see the [API-docs for Random](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29):

> ### `Random`
>
> `public Random(long seed)`
>
> > Creates a new random number generator using a single long seed. The seed is the initial value of the internal state of the pseudorandom number generator which is maintained by method next(int).
> >   
> >      The invocation new Random(seed) is equivalent to:
> >
> > ```
> > Random rnd = new Random();
> > rnd.setSeed(seed);
> > ```
>
> Parameters:
>          `seed` - the initial seed
>      See Also:
>          `setSeed(long)`

---

If you want `r.nextInt(10)` to return the same number *every* call, you need to do:

```
        r.setSeed(123456L);
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
        r.setSeed(123456L);
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
        r.setSeed(123456L);
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
        r.setSeed(123456L);
        System.out.println(r.nextInt(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

DId you use instances of the java.util.Random class or java.lang.Math.random()?

According to the javadoc on Random:

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same seed should produce the same exact sequence on every platform.

Keep in mind that if you are using the same Random object to also do nextBoolean or nextBytes calls in addition to the nextInt calls, and they don't occur in the same exact sequence along with the nextInt calls, that can affect the sequence you get in your nextInt calls. Furthermore, every call to next has to use the same parameter values, or no parameter, in the same sequence every time in order for the returns to be the same.

Every next call to a Random object affects the sequence. Put another way, the nextInt, nextBoolean and nextBytes all interact and affect the sequence, even when you use a seed. To get totally repeatable results, you have to use the same seed with the same exact sequence of next calls.

Below are two pairs of results. The first pair are from generating 100 integers between 0 and 99 and then creating a new Random with the same seed and generating another 100 integers between 0 and 99. The integer sequences are identical, which was expected and in accordance with Java documentation.

The second pair are from generating 100 integers between 0 and 99 and then creating a new Random with the same seed and generating 100 integers between 0 and 99 except that after every 10 integer, a call to the same Random object with alternating calls to nextBoolean and nextBytes occurs. You can see in the results that sequences are repeatable and that calls to same Random object's other next methods affect the sequence from nextInt. You can also see that the general pattern in nextInt continues, but at a later point in the sequence. If the interleaved calls to same Random ojbect's other next methods don't occur exactly the same way every time, the integer sequence will not be the same either.

Two calls to nextInt() for 100 integers between 0 and 99 using seed 123456789L

First set of 100 nextInt(100) calls...

> 65 0 83 44 90 54 33 7 97 87
>
> 41 61 64 82 24 61 60 89 30 79
>
> 42 86 38 54 61 25 98 20 99 88
>
> 65 33 91 30 61 64 27 74 80 13
>
> 58 63 66 38 34 89 46 5 88 79
>
> 50 18 5 24 65 63 58 6 73 80
>
> 84 5 33 1 58 29 9 87 0 83
>
> 1 75 84 81 16 2 8 14 98 26
>
> 64 28 40 50 33 70 81 57 71 18
>
> 58 37 36 48 71 28 95 77 74 92

Second set of 100 nextInt(100) calls...

> 65 0 83 44 90 54 33 7 97 87
>
> 41 61 64 82 24 61 60 89 30 79
>
> 42 86 38 54 61 25 98 20 99 88
>
> 65 33 91 30 61 64 27 74 80 13
>
> 58 63 66 38 34 89 46 5 88 79
>
> 50 18 5 24 65 63 58 6 73 80
>
> 84 5 33 1 58 29 9 87 0 83
>
> 1 75 84 81 16 2 8 14 98 26
>
> 64 28 40 50 33 70 81 57 71 18
>
> 58 37 36 48 71 28 95 77 74 92

As you can see, I get the exact same results.
Now, here is what happens if I inject alternating calls to nextBoolean and nextBytes every 10th call to nextInt() in the second sequence.

Two calls to nextInt() for 100 integers between 0 and 99 using seed 123456789L

First set of 100 nextInt(100) calls...

> 65 0 83 44 90 54 33 7 97 87
>
> 41 61 64 82 24 61 60 89 30 79
>
> 42 86 38 54 61 25 98 20 99 88
>
> 65 33 91 30 61 64 27 74 80 13
>
> 58 63 66 38 34 89 46 5 88 79
>
> 50 18 5 24 65 63 58 6 73 80
>
> 84 5 33 1 58 29 9 87 0 83
>
> 1 75 84 81 16 2 8 14 98 26
>
> 64 28 40 50 33 70 81 57 71 18
>
> 58 37 36 48 71 28 95 77 74 92

Second set of 100 nextInt(100) calls with alternating calls to nextBoolean() and nextBytes(byte[10]) after every 10th call to nextInt(100)...

> 65 0 83 44 90 54 33 7 97 87
>
> false
>
> 61 64 82 24 61 60 89 30 79 42
>
> bytes: -75 -111 34 -128 -92 23 95 -112 100 -76
>
> 61 25 98 20 99 88 65 33 91 30
>
> false
>
> 64 27 74 80 13 58 63 66 38 34
>
> bytes: -118 -57 19 -74 36 -70 31 114 -125 -61
>
> 88 79 50 18 5 24 65 63 58 6
>
> false
>
> 80 84 5 33 1 58 29 9 87 0
>
> bytes: 63 -82 -79 93 -126 2 23 2 -90 122
>
> 84 81 16 2 8 14 98 26 64 28
>
> false
>
> 50 33 70 81 57 71 18 58 37 36
>
> bytes: -8 89 73 71 -25 -104 -28 12 -32 -110
>
> 95 77 74 92 92 78 36 99 78 61
>
> false
>
> 66 39 19 18 19 99 41 68 38 48
>
> bytes: 64 -71 126 97 17 -6 -120 94 73 64

Notice in the resulting pattern, a nextBoolean interleaved eats uses up one integer value from the nextInt sequence and that a nextBytes(byteArray) where byteArray is declared as byte[10] uses up three integer values from the nextInt sequence.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the same value each time, why not just return a fixed int that is set by a single call to a Random?

Comment: he said "values", not "value" and from it's example it seems pretty obvious is after not a single value but a repeatable sequence of pseudo-random **values**

Comment: His first posting was ambiguous. He has since clarified what he is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is that you create your own class and populate it with a list or pre-generated "random" values, created using a Random Number generator.  This is, as far as I know, the technique used by Doom to lower the transmission of data during network games.  All players had the same table of random numbers that would be used to calculate damage, so the actual damage data was not transmitted on the network.

There is an story on the Daily WTF regarding an application where there was the need to actually have a "randomized" list which would be used always:

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/More-or-Less-Random.aspx